# Haxe Macros - replace "function" with "async function"

Tags: javascript, function, replace, macros, haxe

I want that when converting `haxe` to `JavaScript`, asynchronous is added to its methods.
I have `Haxe` code:

```
@:expose
class Main implements IAsync {    
    static function main() {
        trace("test");
    }       

    static function testAwait() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And this code is converted to such a code:

```
. . .
Main.testAwait = function() {
    return Main.test();
};
. . .
```

I wanted to be able replace `function` to `async function` in this code. 
For example:

```
Main.testAwait = async function() {
    return Main.test();
};
```

But I can only change the name of the method for example code macros:

```
package haxe_test;

import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.Context;   
using haxe.macro.Tools;
using haxe_test.AsyncBuilder;

class BuildHub {
    macro static public function build():Array<Field> {
        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
        var testFunc:Function = {
            expr: macro return $v{1},
            ret: null,
            params: [],
            args: []
        };

    fields.push({
        name:  "testAwait",
        access:  [Access.AStatic],
        kind: FieldType.FFun(testFunc),
        pos: Context.currentPos(),
    });
    return fields;  
}
```

How replace `function` to `async function`? 
UPD: I simplified code. Maybe is anythings options compilers or JSGenApi can help me)?

Comment: *asynchronous is added to its methods* why? Not all functions need to be `async`. Or is the `@:async` tag how you want to flag functions that are async? I'm surprised haxe doesn't already support async/await - it used to be such a good language

Comment: just found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/haxe-continuation) - is that at all useful?

Comment: @JaromandaX I simplified code in example,  [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/haxe-continuation) not suitable because I have many legacy code :(

Comment: I think that you might be able to do what you're wanting with by adding metadata to the field when you create it and then adding your own js gen implementation to intercept and generate the appropriate code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your general options would be:

- Collect information about async types/fields in build macros, then use that in `haxe.macro.Context.onAfterGenerate` to modify the output file. Since Haxe code is consistently indented, you can get away with a couple regular expressions (I once made a macro that'd split the output file into multiple by-package files this way).
- Make a slightly modified copy of `haxe.macro.ExampleJSGenerator` to prepend `async` before method declarations of interest. Since you do not need any changes to expression printing, this is also pretty easy.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you considered something more simple but in Haxe 4 you can do something like this:

```
class Test {
  static function main() {
    var value = await( async(testAsync) );
    trace(value);
  }

  static function testAsync() return 1;

  static inline function await<T>(fn:Void->Void):T {
    return js.Syntax.code("await {0}()", fn);
  }
  static inline function async<T>(fn:Void->Void):T {
      return js.Syntax.code("async () => {0}()", fn);
  }
}
```

or do both at same time:

```
class Test {
  static function main() {
    var value = asyncAwait( testAsync );
    trace(value);
  }

  static function testAsync() return 1;

  static inline function asyncAwait<T>(fn:Void->Void):T {
      return js.Syntax.code("(async () => { await {0}() })()", fn);
  }
}
```